# How to declare a variable from a field of the document inside a reduce or map in a aggregation?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection like following:

```
{
  id: 1,
  names: {
    first: 'Ana',
    second: '',
    third: 'Smith',
    four: 'Smitchd'
  },
  used: [
    {
      position: 'first',
      id: 'A'
    },
    {
      position: 'second',
      id: 'B'
    },
  ] 
}
```

I need count how many `used names` have the collections through the documents excluding thoses are empty.

The position of `names` used are saved inside a array called `used`.

In the example i need count the names which exists inside `used`, but in `names` is not empty

I tried a aggregation using a reduce to walk through the arrays `used`, and i can count the items inside the arrays, but i cant use the field names inside the reduce.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $match: id: 1 },
  { $project: { 
    totalUsed: $reduce: {
      input: '$used',
      initialValue: 0,
      in: { $add: ['$$value', { $cond: [{ $eq: ["$$name.$$this.position", '' ]}, 1, 0] }]}
    }
  }}
])
```

I nedd obtain the count of no empty names used... In the example i should get count: 1, because, even when in used existe first and secodn, the field names.second is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it...

I conver the object `names` into a array of object ({ k: key, v: value }), then i declared a variable with `names` (new array) and `used` and use a reduce insed of.

I look for the index in the new array for the key in `$$used.position` on the reduce and then compare if the value is "", and add 1 or 0 depends the case

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $match: id: 1 },
  {
    $project: {
      id: "$id",
      used: { "$used" },
      names: {  $objectToArray : "$names" },
    }
  },
  { 
    $project: {
     totalUsed: {
      $let: {
        vars: { names: "$names", used: "$used" },
        in: {
          $reduce: {
            input: "$$used",
            initialValue: 0,
            in: {
              $add: [
                "$$value",
                  {
                    $cond: [
                      { $eq: [{ $arrayElemAt: ["$$names.v", { $indexOfArray: ["$$names.k", "$$this.position"] } ]}, ""]},
                      0,
                      1
                    ]

                  }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
     }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: { _id: "$id", used: { $sum:"$totalUsed" } }
  }
])
```